# 3-drive RAID-1 on pfSense box

Tags: firewall, raid, freebsd, pfsense, raid1

I have a **pfSense box** with a 2-drive RAID-1 using `gmirror`.  Recently, a drive failed, and I replaced the drive, and the RAID-1 is now back to normal.  But this incident also made me interested in setting up a 3-drive RAID-1, just for the extra redundancy.

Anyway, I figured it would be extremely easy to do this.  Just attach a 3rd drive to the box and use `gmirror insert` to add the new drive to the RAID.

So, I attached a new disk (of the same size as the other 2) via serial ATA to the pfSense box.  Upon reboot, the disk appeared there in /dev as `ada2`.

So, *before* I attempted to add the new disk, `gmirror status` showed the following:

```
                Name    Status  Components
mirror/pfSenseMirror  COMPLETE  ada0 (ACTIVE)
                                ada1 (ACTIVE)
```

Then I typed:

```
gmirror insert pfSenseMirror /dev/ada2
```

After that, I checked the status again with gmirror status, and it showed:

```
                Name    Status  Components
mirror/pfSenseMirror  DEGRADED  ada0 (ACTIVE)
                                ada1 (ACTIVE)
                                ada2 (SYNCHRONIZING, 0%)
```

So it looked like everything was going well ...

But then, a few minutes later, I check gmirror status again, and now it shows:

```
                Name    Status  Components
mirror/pfSenseMirror  DEGRADED  ada0 (ACTIVE)
                                ada2 (SYNCHRONIZING, 9%)
```

So... WTF?  It looks like it kicked off drive `ada1` from the RAID for some reason.

So, what exactly is going on here?  Does `gmirror` inherently limit a RAID 1 to only 2 drives?  Or did I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Under the examples of [gmirror](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gmirror&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) syntax is provided for creating a 3 disk mirror. Apologies for missing it before.

Comment: Although all of the examples show only 2 disks, I don't see anywhere where it explicitly says gmirror is limited to 2 disks only.  Can you elaborate a bit on where it says this in the man pages?

Comment: I was about to edit my post, I skipped right over the example of a 3 disk mirror in the gmirror manpage..